# click event seems to be firing off but the callback statement not work

Tags: jquery

click event seems to be firing off but the callback statement not work.

```
$("#topNorth > ul > li").click(function(event) {    
  alert("test");
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();     
});
```

How can I further troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: How do you know it's "firing off"?

Comment: When using firebug, i turn on log events and see the click event

Comment: Can I see the HTML? (including where your script is placed)

Comment: I'm going to say, 30% chance the selector is wrong, 70% chance there's no doc ready. Waiting for html /popcorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .live() or .on() depending on your jQuery version. Your event will work when the DOM is ready if your selector is correct.